# How do I group query results by calendar month and other variables using Linq2Sql?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a Billing table in my database that contains daily accruals of amounts owed by users based on their usage of the system.  It also contains records of payments received.  For example...

```
BillingID   UserID  Type    Date        Description                 Amount
27298   228 D   11/10/2011 12:00:00 AM  Protection Plan             0.2500
27299   228 D   11/10/2011 12:00:00 AM  Storage Subscription Fee    1.6333
27300   250 D   11/10/2011 12:00:00 AM  Storage Subscription Fee    7.9333
27301   253 D   11/10/2011 12:00:00 AM  Storage Subscription Fee    7.9333
27302   254 D   11/10/2011 12:00:00 AM  Storage Subscription Fee    1.6333
27303   255 D   11/10/2011 12:00:00 AM  Storage Subscription Fee    1.6333
27304   257 D   11/10/2011 12:00:00 AM  Storage Subscription Fee    3.3000
27305   262 D   11/10/2011 12:00:00 AM  Storage Subscription Fee    0.0333
27306   265 D   11/10/2011 12:00:00 AM  Storage Subscription Fee    0.9667
27307   266 D   11/10/2011 12:00:00 AM  Storage Subscription Fee    0.9667
27308   228 D   11/10/2011 12:00:00 AM  Subscription Overage        0.0832
27309   228 D   11/11/2011 12:00:00 AM  Protection Plan             0.2500
27310   228 D   11/11/2011 12:00:00 AM  Storage Subscription Fee    1.6333
27311   250 D   11/11/2011 12:00:00 AM  Storage Subscription Fee    7.9333
27312   253 D   11/11/2011 12:00:00 AM  Storage Subscription Fee    7.9333
```

The data above is not real but it's representative of what I'm working with.  My objective is to write a Linq to Sql query that summarizes this data in an understandable way for the user.  Here's an example of the desired output:

```
User      Month     Type     Description               Amount
228       November   D       Protection Plan            $10   
228       November   D       Storage Subscription Fee   $49
228       November   D       Subscription Overage        $5
228       November   C       Payment                   ($54)
228       December   D       Protection Plan            $10
...
```

I've been able to accomplish part of what I need with the following code:

BusinessLogic.cs File:

```
 public static IEnumerable<Billing> GetBillingHistory(int userid, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        SBMData2.SBMDataContext db = new SBMData2.SBMDataContext();

        return from b in db.Billings
               where b.UserID == userid && b.Date >= startDate && b.Date <= endDate
               select

 new Billing();

        }
```

Code Behind for User Account Page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int userID = foo.Data.User.GetIDFromUserName(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
    DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime startDate = endDate.AddMonths(-3);
    RadGrid2.DataSource = BusinessLogic.GetBillingHistory(userID, startDate, endDate);
    RadGrid2.DataBind();

}
```

The result of this code is a nice grid presented to the user that shows transactions accrued during the last 90 days for that particular user.  How do I modify my Linq query to summarize the results by calendar month, type and description as described in the "desired output" section above? I've been working on this for a long time and am really stumped.  Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping in Linq is the one thing that I don't find easy or obvious:

This I *have* tested (Linqpad is a wonderful toy!)

```
from b in Billings
group b by new { b.UserID, b.Type, Month = b.Date.Value.Month, b.Description } into groupItem
select new 
{
    groupItem.Key.UserID,
    groupItem.Key.Type,
    groupItem.Key.Month,
    groupItem.Key.Description,
    Total = groupItem.Sum (b => b.Amount)
}
```

Converting month number to month name for display is an implementation detail (-:

I look at this and think that it may be possible to express it more elegantly - I think I'm probably missing something in terms of tidy syntax, but its doing what its supposed to do.

Comment: That works beautifully.  Thank you.  I'll probably leave the formatting of the month name for my presentation layer.  The Telerik grid can probably handle that.

Answer (score 1):

I have'nt tested it on machine. You need to play with. But it might work, i think.

```
var listInfo = (from i in context.Billings
                where i.UsreId== id
                group i by new
                { i.UsreId, i.Type, i.DateTime } into newInfo
                select new 
                {
                   UserId,
                   Month,
                   Type,
                   Description,
                   Total= Amount.Count()

                }).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Thanks.  But doesn't that only group by UserID (e.g. not by month, description and type)?

Comment: see updated. Play a little bit, you will get the solution. Or the most easiest way download Linqer and generate the desired Linq from your Sql queries, quickly and easily. Hassle free....

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I'll play around with it.  Thanks also for the tip about Linqer.  It looks like a handy tool for learning Linq.